# Maven Hibernate and Envers - Dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, hibernate-envers

I've got a dependency problem while using Envers.

Somewhere in the world of Envers there is a dependency on the class `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`. This can be found in `hibernate-core.4.1.7.Final`

However, if I use `hibernate-core.4.1.7.Final` then I get a dependency problem (`NoClassDefFoundError`) on `org.hibernate.event.PreCollectionUpdateEventListener` which can be found in `hibernate-core.3.6.10.Final`.

So I'm kind of stuffed because Maven will not put both versions on the classpath.

Any smart people out there with a solution/ideas/fix for this.

Thanks
Adam

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the response @adamw, but that doesn't work. Let me go a bit deeper into what I've done:

`build.xml:`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in my entity code I put:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Company
...
```

Now when I run my integration tests the _AUD tables are not created.

So I add this to the `persistance.xml` file (as instructed [here](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#quickstart)):

```
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.Audit.EventListener" />
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete" value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
  <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate" value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
</properties>
```

And then I get a Spring error resulting in:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

So How do I fix this? Does anyone else have this problem when using Spring, Envers and Maven?

Oh, and by the way. The listeners specified in the `properties.xml` snippet do not exist in either of the jar file dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need to either use Hibernate 4.1.7 with Envers 4.1.7, or Hibernat 3.6.10 with Envers 3.6.10 :)

**Update:**

Now you're using the wrong docs :). You don't need the listeners since 4.x. See here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/ch05.html
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html